# Why can Swift infer the type when there is not enough information?

Tags: swift

I wrote a simple fetch client to handle requests. The code is as follows:

Request

```swift
public protocol RequestParameter: Encodable {
  var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] { get }
}

public extension RequestParameter {
  var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] {
    var this = [URLQueryItem]()
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
    for child in mirror.children {
      guard let label = child.label, let value = child.value as? CustomStringConvertible else {
        continue
      }
      this.append(.init(name: label, value: value.description))
    }
    return this
  }
}

extension Dictionary: RequestParameter where Key == String, Value: CustomStringConvertible & Encodable {
  public var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] {
    var this = [URLQueryItem]()
    for (key, value) in self {
      this.append(.init(name: key, value: value.description))
    }
    return this
  }
}

public protocol Request<Parameter, Response> {
  associatedtype Parameter: RequestParameter
  associatedtype Response: Decodable

  var method: HTTPMethod { get }
  var path: String { get }
  var parameter: Parameter? { get }
  var headers: HTTPHeaders? { get }
}

public extension Request {
  func build(_ urlString: String, encoder: JSONEncoder? = nil) -> URLRequest {
    var components = URLComponents(string: urlString)
    components?.path = path

    if method == .get {
      components?.queryItems = parameter?.queryItems
    }

    guard let url = components?.url else {
      fatalError("url can't be nil")
    }

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    if let headers {
      urlRequest.headers = headers
    }

    if method == .post, let parameter, let encoder {
      do {
        urlRequest.httpBody = try encoder.encode(parameter)
      } catch {
        fatalError("`parameter cannot be encoded`")
      }
    }

    return urlRequest
  }
}
```

Client

```swift
public protocol Client {
  func send<RequestType: Request>(_ request: RequestType, encoder: JSONEncoder?, decoder: JSONDecoder) async throws -> RequestType.Response

  var urlString: String { get }

  static var shared: Self { get }
}

public extension Client {
  func send<RequestType: Request>(_ request: RequestType, encoder: JSONEncoder? = nil, decoder: JSONDecoder = .init()) async throws -> RequestType.Response {
    let (data, urlResponse) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request.build(urlString, encoder: encoder))
    guard let httpResponse = urlResponse as? HTTPURLResponse else {
      throw #InvalidResponse
    }
    guard 200 ... 299 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
      throw #NetworkFailure(httpResponse.statusCode)
    }
    return try decoder.decode(RequestType.Response.self, from: data)
  }
}
```

So a simple and functioning network request code looks like this:

```swift
struct FooRequest: Request {
  typealias Parameter = FooParameter
  typealias Response = Foo

  var method: HTTPMethod = .get
  var path: String = ""
  var parameter: FooParameter? = FooParameter()
  var headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil
}
struct FooParameter: RequestParameter {}
struct Foo: Decodable {}
struct FooClient: Client {
  var urlString: String = "fooURLString.com"

  static var shared: FooClient = Self()
}

let result = try await FooClient.shared.send(FooRequest())
```

But sometimes a simple GET request may not require parameters. In order to avoid duplicating the code `var parameter: FooParameter? = nil` or `var parameter: BarParameter? = nil`，I added a `NeverParameter` type：

```swift
public struct NeverParameter: RequestParameter {
  private init() {}
}

public extension Request where Parameter == NeverParameter {
  var parameter: Parameter? { nil }
}
```

At this point, the problem arose. I thought that with `NeverParameter`, a request would look like this:

```swift
struct FooRequest: Request {
  typealias Parameter = NeverParameter
  typealias Response = Foo

  var method: HTTPMethod = .get
  var path: String = ""
  var headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil
}
```

But actually, commenting out `typealias Parameter = NeverParameter` can still be compiled:

```swift
struct FooRequest: Request {
  // typealias Parameter = NeverParameter
  typealias Response = Foo

  var method: HTTPMethod = .get
  var path: String = ""
  var headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil
}
```

> (lldb) po type(of: parameter)
> Swift.Optional<Request.NeverParameter>

Why can the compiler infer that the type of parameter is `NeverParameter`? even though the default value nil was only added under the where clause of `NeverParameter`?
And adding another `NeverParameter1` with the same implementation, Xcode finally threw an error.：

```swift
public struct NeverParameter: RequestParameter {
  private init() {}
}

public extension Request where Parameter == NeverParameter {
  var parameter: Parameter? { nil }
}

public struct NeverParameter1: RequestParameter {
  private init() {}
}

public extension Request where Parameter == NeverParameter1 {
  var parameter: Parameter? { nil }
}
```

Error:

> Type 'FooRequest' does not conform to protocol 'Request'

Comment: This is not related to the question, but you don't need an extra `NeverParameter` type. You can directly add extensions to the built-in `Never` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associated type inference has been in the language for quite a long time. The trivial case is:

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype T
    func methodThatReturnsT() -> T
}

class Bar: Foo {
    func methodThatReturnsT() -> Int { 1 }
}
```

This is not necessarily how the compiler is implemented, but you can imagine the compiler thinking:

> `Bar` does not have a `T` type. Oh but `methodThatReturnsT` is supposed to return `T`. `Bar.methodThatReturnsT` returns a `Int`, so `T` must be `Int`.

The situation you have here is basically the same, and just a *little* less intuitive because it involves a conditional extension. This behaviour [is found to be rather "magical" by some people](https://forums.swift.org/t/what-kind-of-magic-behavior-is-this/22014/10), and even [reported as a bug](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/52560). This *is* the intended behaviour though.

This is not necessarily how the compiler is implemented, but you can imagine the compiler thinking:

> `FooRequest` doesn't have a declaration for `parameter`. Oh but it is implemented by an extension `extension Request where Parameter == NeverParameter`. Let's use the `parameter` declared there.
>
> `FooRequest` also doesn't have a `Parameter` type, Oh but `parameter` is supposed to be of type `Parameter`. `FooRequest.parameter` (from the extension) is of type `NeverParameter`, so `T` must be `NeverParameter`.

---

This kind of associated type inference is what makes implementing some of the standard library protocols a lot easier than otherwise. For example, consider a typical implementation of [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset-swift.protocol?changes=latest_beta).

```
struct Options: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int
    
    static let option1 = Options(rawValue: 1)
    static let option2 = Options(rawValue: 2)
    static let option3 = Options(rawValue: 4)
}
```

What associated types are involved here? `OptionSet` inherits from `RawRepresentable` and `SetAlgebra`, which in turn inherits from `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`, so there are:

- `RawValue`
- `Element`
- `ArrayLiteralElement`

`RawValue` is inferred based on the declared `rawValue` property, which is intuitive. `OptionSet` declares `Self` as the default for `Element`, so that's no problem. How does `ArrayLiteralElement` get inferred? There is no `init(arrayLiteral:)` initialiser declared, so it can't be inferred from that.

This is same situation that your `FooRequest` is in - a *conditional extension* of `SetAlgebra` helped infer `ArrayLiteralElement` to be the same as `Element`, and that extension provided a default implementation for `init(arrayLiteral:)`.

```
extension SetAlgebra where Element == ArrayLiteralElement {
    public init(arrayLiteral: Element...) { ... }
}
```

See the [extension declaration](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/SetAlgebra.swift#L565) in the Swift source code, or see the docs for that default implementation [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/SetAlgebra.swift#L565).

Comment: Your answer is clear and easy to understand. Thank you.